# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on throwing exception

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm having a problem with a shared library provided by one of our partners and narrowed it down to this test case:

My *own* test library compiled to **`libCrashTestLib.dylib`**:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void Test() {
  try {
    throw std::exception{};
  } catch (const std::exception& e) { }
  std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
}
```

My main executable loads my library and calls the `Test` function:

```
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string lib_path = "/path/to/libCrashTestLib.dylib";

  void* handle = dlopen(lib_path.c_str(), RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
  void (*test_pointer)() = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(dlsym(handle, "Test"));
  test_pointer();
  dlclose(handle);
}
```

This works fine and prints `Success`.

However, when I just link (not even call) the library provided by our partner it gives me an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` where I throw the exception.

What I'm looking for is either of two things:

- A compiler or linker switch that helps me to get rid of this behavior.
- A way to create my own library that crashes this program when I link it, so that I can give our partner more details what thay need to modify.

For completeness, here is the `CMakeLists.txt` I'm using:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(CrashTest CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on)

find_library(VendorApi NAMES vendorapi PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}) 

add_library(CrashTestLib SHARED lib.cpp)
# Uncomment this line to make it crash:
#target_link_libraries(CrashTestLib VendorApi)

add_executable(CrashTestMain main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason for the crash is that the vendor's library is compiled with `libstdc++`, while your code is compliled with `libc++`.

I can trigger a crash quite easily by issuing a cout while constructing a class as part of the library load-time e.g.

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class bongo {

    public:
    bongo() {
        std::cout << "Log something" << std::endl;
    }
};

static class bongo *boing;

void __attribute__((constructor)) start_something(void) {
    boing = new bongo;
}


extern "C" void Test() {
  try {
    throw std::exception{};
  } catch (const std::exception& e) { }
  std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
}
```

loader code:

```
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string lib_path = "./libCrashTestLib.dylib";

  void* handle = dlopen(lib_path.c_str(), RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
  void (*test_pointer)() = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(dlsym(handle, "Test"));
  test_pointer();
  dlclose(handle);
}
```

Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
STDLIB = -stdlib=libstdc++

all: libCrashTestLib.dylib testLib

libCrashTestLib.dylib: CrashTest.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(STDLIB) -shared -o $@ $<

testLib: testLib.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.dylib testLib
```

Invocation:

```
$ make clean && make STDLIB= && ./testLib
rm -f *.dylib testLib
c++ -std=c++11  -shared -o libCrashTestLib.dylib CrashTest.cpp
c++ -std=c++11 -o testLib testLib.cpp
Log something
Success
```

Failing invocation:

```
$ make clean && make && ./testLib
rm -f *.dylib testLib
c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -shared -o libCrashTestLib.dylib CrashTest.cpp
c++ -std=c++11 -o testLib testLib.cpp
Segmentation fault: 11
```

You can check what version of the C++ library is linked to the binary using `otool -L`:

```
$ otool -L libCrashTestLib.dylib
libCrashTestLib.dylib:
    libCrashTestLib.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 104.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer if there is no other one in the next couple of days, since you gave me some new ideas to try. However, both the vendor's and my library are compiled with `libc++`, so it must be something more subtle.